Can't find android SDK inside android studio system options
Very new to android development.
I performed the installation from the https://developer.android.com/ site, as well as Java installation.
I wanted to create an Android Virtual Device, so I just go to Tools > SDK Manager > Appereance & Behavior > System settings
However, I can't see the Android SDK option in system settings. I guess there are some tools that I need to install for the SDK (because I guess this was installed with android studio), but I'm a bit lost on how to proceed.


"I wanted to create an Android Virtual Device" -- go to Tools > AVD Manager or Tools > Device Manager from the main menu, depending on what version of Android Studio you have installed.
